# ulogd installation in RHEL5 - nfnetlink_conntrack sub system is missing - install?

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm trying to install ulogd tool in my system. ulogd requires nfnetlink_conntrack subsystem in the kernel. It seems nfnetlink_conntrack is not available in the Linux version(RHEL5) that I'm using. How to get that in my system? I can not find any info on this in Google, other than I  get a bunch of results that give a link to the source code.

Comment: Actually I found the solution. ulogd works with old kernels also. Only problem is my system was not supporting AF_UNSPEC address family. ulogd tried to use that, and it was failing. I changed the address family from AF_UNSPEC to AF_INET, and it worked!.

Answer (score 0):

Recompile your kernel to enable it:

```
--- Networking support          
      Networking options  --->  
          [*] Network packet filtering framework (Netfilter)  --->
              Core Netfilter Configuration  --->
                  <*>   Connection tracking netlink interface
```